# Pinch zoom in android 2.1

Tags: android, multi-touch, pinch

Is there a way we can achieve Pinch zoom ability to the imageview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code works great! You just have to copy and paste:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;

public class ZoomableImageView extends View {
    private static final String TAG = "ZoomableImageView";       

    private Bitmap imgBitmap = null;

    private int containerWidth;
    private int containerHeight;

    Paint background;   

    //Matrices will be used to move and zoom image
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    PointF start = new PointF();       

    float currentScale;
    float curX;
    float curY;

    //We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    //For animating stuff   
    float targetX;
    float targetY;
    float targetScale;
    float targetScaleX;
    float targetScaleY;
    float scaleChange;
    float targetRatio;
    float transitionalRatio;

    float easing = 0.2f;   
    boolean isAnimating = false;

    float scaleDampingFactor = 0.5f;

    //For pinch and zoom
    float oldDist = 1f;   
    PointF mid = new PointF();

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();       

    float minScale;
    float maxScale = 8.0f;

    float wpRadius = 25.0f;
    float wpInnerRadius = 20.0f;

    float screenDensity;

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public static final int DEFAULT_SCALE_FIT_INSIDE = 0;
    public static final int DEFAULT_SCALE_ORIGINAL = 1;

    private int defaultScale;

    public int getDefaultScale() {
        return defaultScale;
    }

    public void setDefaultScale(int defaultScale) {
        this.defaultScale = defaultScale;
    }

    public ZoomableImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);       
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        screenDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        initPaints();
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());       
    }

    public ZoomableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        screenDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;       
        initPaints();
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());

        defaultScale = ZoomableImageView.DEFAULT_SCALE_FIT_INSIDE;
    }

    private void initPaints() {
        background = new Paint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldWidth, int oldHeight) {
        super.onSizeChanged(width, height, oldWidth, oldHeight);

        //Reset the width and height. Will draw bitmap and change
        containerWidth = width;
        containerHeight = height;

        if(imgBitmap != null) {
            int imgHeight = imgBitmap.getHeight();
            int imgWidth = imgBitmap.getWidth();

            float scale;
            int initX = 0;
            int initY = 0;           

            if(defaultScale == ZoomableImageView.DEFAULT_SCALE_FIT_INSIDE) {               
                if(imgWidth > containerWidth) {           
                    scale = (float)containerWidth / imgWidth;           
                    float newHeight = imgHeight * scale;           
                    initY = (containerHeight - (int)newHeight)/2;

                    matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
                    matrix.postTranslate(0, initY);
                }
                else {           
                    scale = (float)containerHeight / imgHeight;
                    float newWidth = imgWidth * scale;
                    initX = (containerWidth - (int)newWidth)/2;

                    matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
                    matrix.postTranslate(initX, 0);
                }

                curX = initX;
                curY = initY;

                currentScale = scale;
                minScale = scale;
            }
            else {
                if(imgWidth > containerWidth) {                                   
                    initY = (containerHeight - (int)imgHeight)/2;                   
                    matrix.postTranslate(0, initY);
                }
                else {                               
                    initX = (containerWidth - (int)imgWidth)/2;                   
                    matrix.postTranslate(initX, 0);
                }

                curX = initX;
                curY = initY;

                currentScale = 1.0f;
                minScale = 1.0f;               
            }


            invalidate();           
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {               
        if(imgBitmap != null && canvas != null)
        {                                           
            canvas.drawBitmap(imgBitmap, matrix, background);                                                   
        }
    }

    //Checks and sets the target image x and y co-ordinates if out of bounds
    private void checkImageConstraints() {
        if(imgBitmap == null) {
            return;
        }

        float[] mvals = new float[9];
        matrix.getValues(mvals);

        currentScale = mvals[0];

        if(currentScale < minScale) {                               
            float deltaScale = minScale / currentScale;                   
            float px = containerWidth/2;
            float py = containerHeight/2;           
            matrix.postScale(deltaScale, deltaScale, px, py);
            invalidate();
        }       

        matrix.getValues(mvals);
        currentScale = mvals[0];
        curX = mvals[2];
        curY = mvals[5];

        int rangeLimitX = containerWidth - (int)(imgBitmap.getWidth() * currentScale);
        int rangeLimitY = containerHeight - (int)(imgBitmap.getHeight() * currentScale);


        boolean toMoveX = false;
        boolean toMoveY = false;   

        if(rangeLimitX < 0) {
            if(curX > 0) {
                targetX = 0;
                toMoveX = true;
            }
            else if(curX < rangeLimitX) {
                targetX = rangeLimitX;
                toMoveX = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            targetX = rangeLimitX / 2;
            toMoveX = true;
        }

        if(rangeLimitY < 0) {
            if(curY > 0) {
                targetY = 0;
                toMoveY = true;
            }
            else if(curY < rangeLimitY) {
                targetY = rangeLimitY;
                toMoveY = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            targetY = rangeLimitY / 2;
            toMoveY = true;
        }

        if(toMoveX == true || toMoveY == true) {
            if(toMoveY == false) {
                targetY = curY;
            }
            if(toMoveX == false) {
                targetX = curX;
            }           

            //Disable touch event actions
            isAnimating = true;
            //Initialize timer           
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateImagePositionTask);
            mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateImagePositionTask, 100);
        }
    }       


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {       
        if(gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
            return true;
        }

        if(isAnimating == true) {
            return true;
        }

        //Handle touch events here       
        float[] mvals = new float[9];
        switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if(isAnimating == false) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());           
                mode = DRAG;               
            }
        break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            oldDist = spacing(event);           
            if(oldDist > 10f) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                midPoint(mid, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
            }
        break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = NONE;

            matrix.getValues(mvals);
            curX = mvals[2];
            curY = mvals[5];
            currentScale = mvals[0];

            if(isAnimating == false) {                                       
                checkImageConstraints();
            }
        break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:           
            if(mode == DRAG && isAnimating == false) {
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                float diffX = event.getX() - start.x;
                float diffY = event.getY() - start.y;

                matrix.postTranslate(diffX, diffY);

                matrix.getValues(mvals);
                curX = mvals[2];
                curY = mvals[5];
                currentScale = mvals[0];
            }
            else if(mode == ZOOM && isAnimating == false) {
                float newDist = spacing(event);               
                if(newDist > 10f) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float scale = newDist / oldDist;                   
                    matrix.getValues(mvals);
                    currentScale = mvals[0];

                    if(currentScale * scale <= minScale) {
                        matrix.postScale(minScale/currentScale, minScale/currentScale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }                   
                    else if(currentScale * scale >= maxScale) {
                        matrix.postScale(maxScale/currentScale, maxScale/currentScale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                    else {
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }


                    matrix.getValues(mvals);
                    curX = mvals[2];
                    curY = mvals[5];
                    currentScale = mvals[0];                                       
                }
            }

        break;                               
        }

        //Calculate the transformations and then invalidate
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x/2, y/2);
    }

    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap b) {       
        if(b != null) {
            imgBitmap = b;               

            containerWidth = getWidth();
            containerHeight = getHeight();

            int imgHeight = imgBitmap.getHeight();
            int imgWidth = imgBitmap.getWidth();

            float scale;
            int initX = 0;
            int initY = 0;

            matrix.reset();

            if(defaultScale == ZoomableImageView.DEFAULT_SCALE_FIT_INSIDE) {               
                if(imgWidth > containerWidth) {           
                    scale = (float)containerWidth / imgWidth;           
                    float newHeight = imgHeight * scale;           
                    initY = (containerHeight - (int)newHeight)/2;

                    matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
                    matrix.postTranslate(0, initY);
                }
                else {           
                    scale = (float)containerHeight / imgHeight;
                    float newWidth = imgWidth * scale;
                    initX = (containerWidth - (int)newWidth)/2;

                    matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
                    matrix.postTranslate(initX, 0);
                }

                curX = initX;
                curY = initY;

                currentScale = scale;
                minScale = scale;
            }
            else {
                if(imgWidth > containerWidth) {
                    initX = 0;
                    if(imgHeight > containerHeight) {                       
                        initY = 0;
                    }
                    else {                       
                        initY = (containerHeight - (int)imgHeight)/2;
                    }

                    matrix.postTranslate(0, initY);
                }
                else {                               
                    initX = (containerWidth - (int)imgWidth)/2;
                    if(imgHeight > containerHeight) {
                        initY = 0;
                    }
                    else {
                        initY = (containerHeight - (int)imgHeight)/2;
                    }
                    matrix.postTranslate(initX, 0);
                }

                curX = initX;
                curY = initY;

                currentScale = 1.0f;
                minScale = 1.0f;               
            }

            invalidate();           
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "bitmap is null");
        }
    }

    public Bitmap getPhotoBitmap() {       
        return imgBitmap;
    }


    private Runnable mUpdateImagePositionTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {       
            float[] mvals;

            if(Math.abs(targetX - curX) < 5 && Math.abs(targetY - curY) < 5) {
                isAnimating = false;
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateImagePositionTask);

                mvals = new float[9];
                matrix.getValues(mvals);

                currentScale = mvals[0];
                curX = mvals[2];
                curY = mvals[5];

                //Set the image parameters and invalidate display
                float diffX = (targetX - curX);
                float diffY = (targetY - curY);

                matrix.postTranslate(diffX, diffY);
            }
            else {
                isAnimating = true;
                mvals = new float[9];
                matrix.getValues(mvals);

                currentScale = mvals[0];
                curX = mvals[2];
                curY = mvals[5];

                //Set the image parameters and invalidate display
                float diffX = (targetX - curX) * 0.3f;
                float diffY = (targetY - curY) * 0.3f;

                matrix.postTranslate(diffX, diffY);               
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 25);               
            }

            invalidate();           
        }
    };

    private Runnable mUpdateImageScale = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {           
            float transitionalRatio = targetScale / currentScale;           
            float dx;
            if(Math.abs(transitionalRatio - 1) > 0.05) {
                isAnimating = true;               
                if(targetScale > currentScale) {                                       
                    dx = transitionalRatio - 1;
                    scaleChange = 1 + dx * 0.2f;

                    currentScale *= scaleChange;

                    if(currentScale > targetScale) {
                        currentScale = currentScale / scaleChange;
                        scaleChange = 1;
                    }
                }
                else {                                   
                    dx = 1 - transitionalRatio;                   
                    scaleChange = 1 - dx * 0.5f;
                    currentScale *= scaleChange;

                    if(currentScale < targetScale) {
                        currentScale = currentScale / scaleChange;
                        scaleChange = 1;
                    }
                }


                if(scaleChange != 1) {
                    matrix.postScale(scaleChange, scaleChange, targetScaleX, targetScaleY);               
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateImageScale, 15);
                    invalidate();
                }
                else {
                    isAnimating = false;
                    scaleChange = 1;                   
                    matrix.postScale(targetScale/currentScale, targetScale/currentScale, targetScaleX, targetScaleY);
                    currentScale = targetScale;
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateImageScale);
                    invalidate();
                    checkImageConstraints();
                }               
            }
            else {
                isAnimating = false;
                scaleChange = 1;               
                matrix.postScale(targetScale/currentScale, targetScale/currentScale, targetScaleX, targetScaleY);
                currentScale = targetScale;
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateImageScale);
                invalidate();
                checkImageConstraints();
            }                               
        }
    };

   /** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
   private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE", "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      int action = event.getAction();
      int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
      sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);
      if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
         sb.append("(pid ").append(action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
         sb.append(")");
      }
      sb.append("[");

      for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
         sb.append("#").append(i);
         sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
         sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
         sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
         if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
            sb.append(";");
      }
      sb.append("]");
   }

   class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {           
            if(isAnimating == true) {
                return true;
            }

            scaleChange = 1;
            isAnimating = true;
            targetScaleX = event.getX();
            targetScaleY = event.getY();

            if(Math.abs(currentScale - maxScale) > 0.1) {           
                targetScale = maxScale;
            }
            else {
                targetScale = minScale;
            }
            targetRatio = targetScale / currentScale;
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateImageScale);
            mHandler.post(mUpdateImageScale);           
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just create a class called ZoomableImageView, copy and paste all code. Then, add this view inside either your layout file or programmatically and use setImageBitmap method for assigning an Image which has to be zoomable. Zoom is handled directly inside ZoomableImageView class (onTouch method).