# Android: Different Devices place Matrix on different spots, despite same x and y

Tags: android, canvas, matrix

I am using this code [Pinch zoom in android 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407072/pinch-zoom-in-android-2-1) (by kinghomer) within an Activity within a Tabhost. I am using that to display a background image, and then also display icons on that image. These icons have to be displayed at the spot that i have defined (i give the matrix x and y coordinates). This is all working.

The problem that i have is that in some devices, the icons aren't on the exact same spot, but about 1cm off in each the x and y coordinates. I have tried to recreate this in an emulator, using the same resolution as one of those devices, however, in the emulator, with the same resolution as one of the devices where it is "wrong", they are shown on the correct spots. I have no idea what is causing this?

I have tried the app on an HTC sensation running 4.0.3 (displaying the icons correctly) and a samsung galaxy s3 running 4.1.2 (displaying them incorrectly, each coordinate is off about 1cm.). I have emulators with the same resolution as each of these devices, but in both those emulators the icons are displayed correctly.

What is causing this? I'd be grateful for any ideas!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's impossible to help you without knowing how you determine your coordinates.  Are you plotting coordinates according to screen dimensions?

Comment: The coordinates are pixels on the background image. This image then gets scaled according to the screen, and is placed in the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My error was that i thought since i needed to have the exact pixel as x and y coordinate on my background picture, that i should put that picture as well as the icons only into the drawable-hdpi folder (completely disregarding the other drawable folders), so that Android is forced to take the same images. I couldn't rescale them and put the accordingly scaled pictures into the other folders, because then the pixel coordinates would be off. However, i just put the exact same images into each of the drawable folders, and Android takes care of the rest. Quite embarrassing really. Thanks @MarsAtomic for trying to help!